# Model's normal method mistaken by attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `TelegramUser`extending `Model` with two simple identical functions:

```
public function toString() {
    if ($this->telegram_first_name != null) {
        return $this->telegram_first_name;
    } else if ($this->telegram_username != null) {
        return $this->telegram_username;
    }
}

public function getDisplayName() {
    if ($this->telegram_first_name != null) {
        return $this->telegram_first_name;
    } else if ($this->telegram_username != null) {
        return $this->telegram_username;
    }
}
```

If I call the toString method from outside the class (e.g. `$telegramUser->toString()`) everthing works as espected, but if I call toString from inside the `TelegramUser` model this happens:

```
local.ERROR: LogicException: App\TelegramUser::toString must return a relationship instance. in webapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:416
Stack trace:
#0 webapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(399): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getRelationshipFromMethod('toString')
#1 webapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(329): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getRelationValue('toString')
#2 webapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1519): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getAttribute('toString')
#3 webapp/app/TelegramUser.php(79): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__get('toString')
```

this is the function inside the TelegramUser model where I'm calling the toString function:

```
public function giftableKarma($chatId, $karmaType, $karmaCount) {
    Log::debug("$this->toString() wants to donate $karmaCount unit(s) of $karmaType->name");
 ...
}
```

Tring to put the toString outside the string like this:

```
    Log::debug($this->toString() . " wants to donate $karmaCount unit(s) of $karmaType->name");
```

leads to the same error.

That's why I have defined the `getDisplayName` which works *only if* I put it outside the string, so:

```
    Log::debug($this->getDisplayName() . " wants to donate $karmaCount unit(s) of $karmaType->name");
```

Will happily work and log the user's first name or username, while this:

```
    Log::debug("$this->getDisplayName() wants to donate $karmaCount unit(s) of $karmaType->name");
```

Will lead to the same `LogicException` error, this time obviously referred to the getDisplayName "attribute"

So my two questions are:

1. Why the `toString` method works while calling the code from outside the class and won't work inside the `giftableKarma` method?
2. Why the getDisplayName will fire the same exception if it's put inside the log's string?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error you're seeing has anything to do with calling the function outside the class or inside the class, and everything to do with PHP string parsing and Laravel's magic methods.

[PHP's string parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) allows you to insert variable names, but not functions. In other words, if you do the following: `"$this->toString()"` PHP will think the name of your variable is `$this->toString`, not `$this->toString()`.

So, when you use it like that it is trying to access a class property named `toString` instead of execute the method named `toString()`.

In Laravel, Models have a magic method (`__get()`) that allows you to resolve both model attributes and relations dynamically, which allows you to use, e.g., `$mymodel->myattribute` without having to explicitly define that property on the class. So, when you try to call `$this->toString` (without the trailing parentheses), Laravel first looks to see if this model has an attribute named `toString` and if so, returns it's value. If not, it looks for a function named `toString()` and expects it to define a relationship. This last one is what is happening to you.

I wouldn't use the `toString` for a method name, because it's too close to the magic method called `__toString()`, which allows you to define an implicit conversion of a class to a string (Laravel actually already has this defined in it's Model class, as well).

For your particular problem, if you want to use the value inside a string, you can get around the string parsing limitation by surrounding it with curly brackets (which is a good habit to establish anyway to avoid confusion):

```
Log::debug("{$this->toString()} wants to...");
```

Alternatively, a nifty feature in Laravel is the [virtual accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), which you can define like this:

```
public function getDisplayNameAttribute() {
    if ($this->telegram_first_name != null) {
        return $this->telegram_first_name;
    } else if ($this->telegram_username != null) {
        return $this->telegram_username;
    }
}
```

You basically define a function that starts with `get` and ends with `Attribute` and Laravel magically maps that to whatever word(s) you stick in between so you can access it like a native property.

Then, you can then do:

```
Log::debug("$this->displayName wants to...");
```

and it should work.